# How to turn off logging of generated code in Apache Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently upgraded a project to Apache Spark 2.1.0.

The code generation feature writes generated code contents to standard out. For example:

```
// Class file version = 49.0 (J2SE 5.0)

package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions;

public class GeneratedClass extends codegen.GeneratedClass {

// Enclosing/enclosed types:
//   GeneratedClass { final class GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator }

public Object generate(Object[] p1) {
    new             GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator
    dup            
    aload           [this]
    aload           [Object[] p1]
    invokespecial   GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator(GeneratedClass, Object[])
    areturn        
}
```

Though I've found the option `spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage` to enable/disable code generation, I haven't found any options to turn off just the output of the generated code.

Is this controlled via a spark option? Logging config?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```